# How do I unmerge my changes that i have already merge into develop

Tags: git, github

I have run the command `git push origin develop` and it merged my old branches into `develop`.. but I don't want to merge this.

How can I unmerge my branches from `develop`?

Comment: https://www.datree.io/resources/git-undo-merge

Comment: Pushing will not do a merge. It was either done by a `git merge` or a `git pull`.

Comment: so how to solve when i am pushing my data into develop branch and how to unmerge my branches those are merged by develop?